# Como organizar um array por tamanho automaticamente?

Tags: php, array, order

Eu estava querendo criar um sistema de ranking. Para isso eu pensei em colocar todos os valores dentro de um `Array` e depois por meio de uma função organizá-lo do maior para o menor. Porém, cada vez que faço cada posição, eu sempre tenho que fazer um código maior (e eu não sei quantos registros terão). O código seria semelhante a isso :

```
<?php
  // essa função recebe um array como parâmetro
  function ordenaArray($array){
     $arrayOrdenado = array();
     $indice = 0;
     $maior = 0;
     for($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++){
       if($array[$i] >= $maior){
           $maior = $array[$i];
       }
     }
   $arrayOrdenado[$indice] = $maior;
   $indice++;
  }
?>
```

Eu consigo fazer isso para todos os registros, mas como eu nunca vou saber quantos registros terão, vou continuar fazendo isso para vários outros registros.

Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso mais dinamicamente?

> Para quem ainda não entendeu, eu quero que um array `x=(1,4,3,2,5,6,9,8,7,0)` vire um array `y=(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)`

Comment: função [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma função que inverte o *array* em PHP, que se chama [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php):

```
<?php
$input  = array("php", 4.0, array("green", "red"));
$reversed = array_reverse($input);
$preserved = array_reverse($input, true);

print_r($input);
print_r($reversed);
print_r($preserved);
?>
```

Pelo que entendi ela te atende.

Caso precise ordenar primeiro use desta forma:

```
<?php
 $array = array('d', '1', 'b', '3', 'a', '0', 'c', '2');

 sort($array); // Classifica o Array em ordem Crescente.

 print_r($array); // Resultado: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => a [5] => b [6] => c [7] => d )

 echo '<br/>';

 rsort($array); // Classifica o Array em ordem Decrescente.

 print_r($array); // Resultado: Array ( [0] => d [1] => c [2] => b [3] => a [4] => 3 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 0 )
?>
```

O comando [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php) fará o trabalho.

Ou seja:

- Se quiser ordenar use `sort`
- Se quiser inverter use `rsort`

Comment: a problema não é nem inverter o array, e sim ordená-lo  na sequencia correta

Comment: Acrescente mais detalhes, o comando sort ordena o array

Comment: cara, é exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado!

Comment: nada precisando tamos aê. :)

Comment: se puder marcar como certa e dar upvote :)